# jQuery timer pauses when browser is out of focus

Tags: jquery

I'm facing this problem in Chrome and Mozilla, while IE works fine. The timer pauses when I minimize the browser or open a new tab and work on that tab for a while, but then resumes again if the web application is in focus again. I know this by the difference in the time, e.g. after about a minute or so only a second or so will have elapsed when I return to the web application. I don't know what is causing this issue.

Here is the jQuery snippet that I used, the timer can be downloaded from here http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/

```
 var countdownTimer, countdownCurrent;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        countdownCurrent = $('#ctl00_MainContent_example2submit').val() * 100;
        countdownTimer = $.timer(function () {
            var min = parseInt(countdownCurrent / 6000);
            var sec = parseInt(countdownCurrent / 100) - (min * 60);
            var micro = pad(countdownCurrent - (sec * 100) - (min * 6000), 2);
            var output = "00"; if (min > 0) { output = pad(min, 2); }
            $('.countdowntime').html(output + ":" + pad(sec, 2) + ":" + micro);
            if (countdownCurrent == 0) {
                $('#ctl00_MainContent_btnNext').click();

            } else {
                countdownCurrent -= 7;
                if (countdownCurrent < 0) { countdownCurrent = 0; }
            }
        }, 70, true);


        $('#example2submit').bind('keyup', function (e) { if (e.keyCode == 13) { countdownReset(); } });

    });

    function CheckIfOptionSelected() {

        var vFlag = true;
        var radioButton1 = document.forms[0].elements['ctl00_MainContent_rdBtnListOptions_0'];
        var radioButton2 = document.forms[0].elements['ctl00_MainContent_rdBtnListOptions_1'];
        var radioButton3 = document.forms[0].elements['ctl00_MainContent_rdBtnListOptions_2'];
        var radioButton4 = document.forms[0].elements['ctl00_MainContent_rdBtnListOptions_3'];

        if (radioButton1.checked == false && radioButton2.checked == false && radioButton3.checked == false && radioButton4.checked == false && countdownCurrent > 0) {
            vFlag = false;
        }

        else {
            countdownReset();
            vFlag = true;
        }
        return vFlag;
    }

    function countdownReset() {
        var newCount = parseInt($('#ctl00_MainContent_example2submit').val()) * 100;
        if (newCount > 0) { countdownCurrent = newCount; }
        countdownTimer.stop().once();
                }

    // Padding function
    function pad(number, length) {
        var str = '' + number;
        while (str.length < length) { str = '0' + str; }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem here? In other words, what behavior do you want the page to have? Forget about jQuery and timers and all that and describe in detail what you are trying to make the page do. Also, note that timers are not precise. A timer may fire later than expected even if the page is open. If you are updating a time display you can't base it on how many times a timer has fired. You need to use a Date object instead.

Comment: thanks michael for the reply...i just want examinees to have a limited time for questions . If they run out of time i.e after timer elpase is detected...the jquery clicks the next button and examinee will be presented with next question. The problem i'm facing is...if the examinee just minimizes the browser, the timer pauses and he'll have all the time in world to do anything. I want to prevent that. And you mentioned date objects??...can they be used for such a purpose?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that's very helpful. I think I have some ideas for you - I wrote it up as an answer so I could format the code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at that jQuery timer plugin, and I don't like the code much. It seems unnecessarily complicated for a simple task. Code like this does not inspire confidence:

```
if(typeof func == 'object') {
    var paramList = ['autostart', 'time'];
    for(var arg in paramList) {if(func[paramList[arg]] != undefined) {eval(paramList[arg] + " = func[paramList[arg]]");}};
    func = func.action;
}
```

Reformatted with some much-needed line breaks and comments added:

```
if(typeof func == 'object') {
    var paramList = ['autostart', 'time'];
    // Never use for..in to iterate over an array
    for(var arg in paramList) {
        if(func[paramList[arg]] != undefined) {
            // What does this eval code do and why?
            eval(paramList[arg] + " = func[paramList[arg]]");
        }
    };
    func = func.action;
}
```

If you need a timer that works, why not take a simpler approach and use the browser's `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` directly? And if you need to know how much time has elapsed, use `+new Date` to get the current time in milliseconds and subtract as needed.

Here's a test page that displays the number of seconds since the page was loaded. It's pure native HTML and JavaScript code and I think it should work in every browser. In particular, it works as expected when IE is minimized. You could use this as a starting point for a simple and reliable solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Time Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <code>
        This page has been open for
        <span id="timeOpen">0</span>
        seconds
    </code>

    <script>
        var timeStart = +new Date;
        setInterval( function() {
            var timeNow = +new Date;
            var secondsOpen = ( timeNow - timeStart ) / 1000;
            document.getElementById('timeOpen').innerHTML =
                Math.floor( secondsOpen );
        }, 250 );
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/unNZk/).

Comment: hello michael thanks for the reply...i'm not so good at Jquery...still learning...i just download the free codes and reference them in my asp.net application....the code above looks gr8 and promising..i'll try that out in my site...thaks again man. Cheers!